# Get Python source before execution

Tags: python, command-line, interpreter

I would like to catch (and modify at some stage) the code being fed to a Python interpreter before the interpreter gets to process all of it, but from within the interpreter.

The use case I have in mind is as following:

```sh
python "import black_magic; ... some python code ..."
```

and the `import black_magic` actually catches and process whatever follows, before feeding it back to the Python interpreter.

For example, something like this (I know this is a silly example):

```sh
python "import black_magic; print(voodoo)"
```

and the `print(voodoo)` code becomes `print("Voodoo magic")`.

A less silly example would be, e.g.:

```sh
python "import black_magic; for i in 1:100: print(i)"
```

so that `1:100` gets converted to `range(1:100)`.

The question is then: what should I write in a `black_magic` module to make sure that I catch `for i in 1:100: print(i)` before is being interpreted?

Comment: That's mock's job: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: @ipaleka I do not see how you would do it with `unittest.mock`, would you have an example on that?

Answer (score 0):

I have one file named `vd2.py` which contains `print("Hello World")`.

I have another file named `vd1.py` which contains:

```
import argparse
import system

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

val = open(args.filename, 'r')
lines = val.readlines()
val.close()
val2 = open("vd2.py", 'w')
replacelist = ["Hello World"]
replacewith = ["Voodoo"]
for j in range(len(replacelist)):
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if replacelist[j] in lines[i]:
            lines[i] = lines[i].replace(replacelist[j], replacewith[j])
        val2.write(lines[i])
val2.close()

os.system("python3 " + args.filename)
```

From the command line in the local directory I can now type `python3 vd1.py vd2.py`, which changes the contents of `vd2.py` to `print("Voodoo")`.

The output is `Voodoo`.

Comment: the question is more how to do it in absence of a file.